# Firefox issue when using text-transform with text-overflow

Tags: html, css, firefox

Hope you doing good.

I faced the following hazardous issue (please run the snippet using ***firefox*** on ***Windows*** or ***Linux***) :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .content {
                background-color: red;
                width: 200px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }

            .content .text {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }

            .content .text:first-letter {
                text-transform: capitalize;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">code mapping</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">code postal</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">zipe codigo</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">some div</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">foo bar zoo</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">The expected behavior for the ellipsis</div>
            <div>(i)</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue is that when I capitalize the first letter it breaks the expected text-overflow behavior.

He is a screenshot of the snippet result for me (as I'm not sure if it depends on my Firefox language or anything else) :
[image]

But depending on the text content it does not have the same behavior.

Big kudos if you can :

1. Explain me why it behaves differently depending on the string (only the "code postal" string is ellipsed for me in the sample)
2. Tell me how I can avoid the ellispis when the parents width is not reached ?

Have a nice day !

**Edit 1:**
Ok somehow replacing `capitalize` with `uppercase` solves the problem. But does not really answer the original question. And it creates some unexpected space between divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on firefox. I am on a mac though. You can try adding a `max-width: calc(100% - 15px)` to the `.text`. Check [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4b5x3dza/)

Comment: Thank for giving it a try !
Indeed I just tried on my mac and it works. However not on Ubuntu nor Windows.
Your fiddle unfortunately does not change anything :(